# Detect if UIImageViews touch/overlap

Tags: ios, swift

Trying to figure out how to detect if two of my ImageViews overlap. I don't have any code because I don't know where to start. I already have code to drag the bigger circle. When I drag the bigger circle, and when the bigger circle covers the smaller circle I want the smaller circle to disappear and spawn in a random location inside the view controller. Like the bigger circle is eating the smaller circle. Also, if possible how would I connect this to my score so that everytime the smaller circle gets eaten it adds a point? I know this is a lot to ask, but this is my first app and trying to get the basics. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So the specifics of when you want the smaller circle to disappear depends on exactly how you define it, but a good start is to find the location of the bigger view from its gesture recognizer and identify if the location is within the smaller view's frame from the gesture recognizer function. This definition ensures that the bigger circle will overlap the smaller circle since the radius is larger. So if the bigger imageView has a pangesturerecognizer, use a switch case to determine when the imageview is being dragged or has stopped dragging and then remove the smallerImageView from the superview. This can be done like such:

```
switch sender.state{
     case .changed:
          if smallerImageView.contains(sender.location(in: self.view)){
               smallerImageView.removeFromSuperView()
               // This will remove the smallerImageView entirely. Here sender is the gesture recognizer.
          }
     default:
     break;
}
```

To add a point once the bigger image view has eaten the smaller one i would set the tag value of the view and then make the imageView have a larger frame. See here for more on the tage property: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622493-tag

Comment: How would you find the location of the view from a gesture recognizer function? And what do you mean by sender is the gesture recognizer?

Comment: You said you were able to drag the bigger circle, so I assumed you were doing it with a pan gesture. How are you implementing the dragging feature. I can help if you show me some code.

Comment: I posted another question, this provides the code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45123971/switch-case-in-pangesture

Answer (score 0):

First, test the view's frames to see if they overlap. You can use the `CGRect` `intersects(_:)` method to see if the frames intersect at all. That will be very fast.

Once you determine that the rects intersect, what constitutes overlap is application-specific. It is possible to test for overlap in the non-opaque parts of two images, but it's pretty complex and computationally expensive.

If your problem is simply determining if two circles overlap, or if one completely contains the other, you just need to use the Pythagorean theorem to calculate the distance between the circle centers and do some checking.

After a little head-scratching, here's what I came up with:

Let's call the circles A and B. 
Let's call the center points of the two circles (A.x, A.y) and (B.x, B.y). 
Let's call the distance between the centers `d(A,B)`. 
Let's call the sum of the raidiuses `rA + rb`. 
Let's call the radius of A minus the radius of B `rA - rB`, and the radius of B minus the radius of A `rB - rA`

The distance between the 2 centers `d(A,B)` is `sqrt((A.x - B.x)^2 + (A.y - B.y)^2)`.

They don't overlap at all if the distance between the two circles is > the sum of their radiuses `d(A,B) > (rA + rB)`.

If the distance between them `d(A,B)` is equal to `rA + rB` {`d(A,B) = rA + rB`}, they touch at one point.

If the distance between the centers `d(A,B)` is less than the sum of the radiuses `d(A,B) < rA + rB` there is some overlap.

If the distance between the centers `d(A,B)` is <= than the radius of A minus the radius of B `d(A,B) <= (rA - rB)`, circle A completely contains circle B.

If the distance between the centers `d(A,B)` is <= than the radius of B minus the radius of A `d(A,B) <= (rB - rA)`, circle B completely contains circle A.

Comment: So how would I convert the final step into code? And also How would I test if the two images overlapped? Very new to Xcode.

Comment: "How would I test if the two images overlapped"?!?! I just gave a lengthy answer telling you exactly that.

Comment: Take the logic that I outlined and try to write a method that takes two objects as input (center position and radius) and returns an enum: noOverlap, partialOverlap, firstEnclosesSecond, secondEnclosesFirst, same (where same means the radius and center values both match). If you get stuck, edit your question and post the code you're stuck on.

Comment: If writing that function is beyond your current abilities then you are trying to do do much too soon and need to start with simpler exercises first.